# What causes "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: c#, .net, webexception

I've got a downloader app. It works fine for me, but one user send me bug report saying that System.Net.WebException is throwed with 'Unable to connect to the remote server', while it works for the link good on my pc. It works with other links but with this particular, don't. What causes this exception? And what can be the difference between my pc configuration and his.

Comment: Make sure you and your client are not using "localhost" as the server name.

Comment: Is a firewall running on his machine? Maybe he is having network problems, too.

Comment: because your machine (which I assume is a development machine) probably contains the service needed by whichever client program you wrote, however your user would ideally be connecting to a real server, not his own machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program can't find the server in a resonable timeframe. As the link works for you, this is probably a local problem. Maybe blocked by a filter, dns resolve doesn't work, long route through servers, problem with a backbone on the route.

Please ask your user to confirm wether he can open the link regulary outside your program. If this doesn't work either, the fault isn't on your side. If he should be able to, you'll need to provide extensive logging code which will help you pin the issue. However, it is very much possible that you'll never find the bug unless you are able to debug the application on his machine with his environment.

Comment: Actually it's a link to youtube video, and it's generated. That's why it's hard to reopen it on his computer. The strange part is that only this particular youtube vid doesn't work for him.

Comment: hm, maybe youtube blocks access to the video on ip adress? That could also cause this. I would create a client with some logging (catch the WebException, it has a `Response` property which should show you the exact cause).